# Capacitor Quasar "Geolocation" plugin is not implemented on android

Tags: android, capacitor, quasar

I added capacitor via the quasar framework. I didn't add any plugin at first and everything worked perfectly. Then I updgraded to capacitor v3. I followed the guide and my app worked also without any problems. Then I added the geolocation plugin to capacitor. It works as expected in the browser, but when I try it on my native android device it gives me this error:

> "Geolocation" plugin is not implemented on android

It looks like I didn't install the plugin, but as I said, it works in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok fixed it, by checking both package.json files (also the one in /src-capacitor). I used capacitor 3 in my web project but capacitor 2 in my capacitor project. I wanted to use v3 so I tried to access the plugin in the way of capacitor v3 which did not work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I had also a version problem and I had to delete the src-capacitor/android folder and reinstall everything after changing the versions.

Comment: Please, let me know, how step by step resolve this problem? Should I remove any folder in my project?

Comment: Ok, I upgradet Capacitor from v2 to v3 according to https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-capacitor-apps/capacitor-version-support. And now, I have empty MainActivity class as explained at https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#switch-to-automatic-android-plugin-loading. But the problem still exists... "Error: "Geolocation" plugin is not implemented on android". After all, documentation in Capacitor v3 plugins register themselves

Comment: I didnt remove any folder in my case. Just view your package.json in your root project and in your /src-capacitor. Both of them must import the packages for capacitor v3

Comment: There it is a simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74518387/11296031

Answer (score 1):

This is because Capacitor changes the underlying Gradle files but Android Studio doesn't know.
To fix this, go to Android studio click File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
[image]